# How to implement coundowntimer to run beyond the limit?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, android-timer

i am working on a application in which i am using `CountDownTimer` for timer purpose which runs from the start time given to upto 0 and then receives a callback in `onFinish()`, but i want it to run in negative value. say, if timer is set for 1 minutes and its over then it should continue in -ve value instead of stooping the countdowntimer .

How to do that, or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: why do you want to do that? you might be using the wrong tool, or there could be better ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thats what i am asking, i am currently using countdown timer for implementing timer , but it dosent allow to run it beyond the limit

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for late answer but I hope this will helpful someone who also whats to do same as this question.*

Fist android provide **CountDownTimer** class to perform count down timer operation. In this class timer stop while time is 0 hour, 0 minute, 0 second and  `onFinish()` method call.
so If we want to go in minus value we need some line to comment out means in other word we have to make our custom class for count down timer. so here is custom class which can goes in minus value also. Just past it in your project and import this class instead of original CountDownTimer class.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;


public abstract class CustomCountDownTimer {
    /**
     * Millis since epoch when alarm should stop.
     */
    private final long mMillisInFuture;

    /**
     * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
     */
    private final long mCountdownInterval;

    private long mStopTimeInFuture;

    /**
     * boolean representing if the timer was cancelled
     */
    private boolean mCancelled = false;

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */
    public CustomCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        mMillisInFuture = millisInFuture;
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
    }

    /**
     * Cancel the countdown.
     */
    public synchronized final void cancel() {
        mCancelled = true;
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    /**
     * Start the countdown.
     */
    public synchronized final CustomCountDownTimer start() {
        mCancelled = false;

        //if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
        //onFinish();
        //return this;
        //}

        mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
        return this;
    }


    /**
     * Callback fired on regular interval.
     *
     * @param millisUntilFinished The amount of time until finished.
     */
    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    /**
     * Callback fired when the time is up.
     */
    public abstract void onFinish();


    private static final int MSG = 1;


    // handles counting down
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            synchronized (CustomCountDownTimer.this) {
                if (mCancelled) {
                    return;
                }

                final long millisLeft = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                //if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                //  onFinish();
                //} else
                //        if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                // no tick, just delay until done
                //      sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                //      } else {
                long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                onTick(millisLeft);

                // take into account user's onTick taking time to execute
                long delay = lastTickStart + mCountdownInterval - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                // special case: user's onTick took more than interval to
                // complete, skip to next interval
                while (delay < 0) delay += mCountdownInterval;

                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                //   }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**important :** here we remove `onFinish()` method from condition so it won't be finish you have to call `onFinsh()` method as per your requrement